# How to add a jquery slider in an html4/css2 webpage at a particular place.

Tags: jquery, html, css

Friends
I have created an website with HTML4/CSS2. And now i want to add an jquery image slider. But, i haven't work with jquery. And i have downloded some free jquery slider. But, the problem is i have not been able to set them in a particular place. I am in a fix. please help me out.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation of the slider? and also its hard to fix something when we cant see any code or when we don't know the name of the particular slider you are using. More information is required in your question, its quite vague.

Comment: post your code, what have you done, which "free" slider do you use, and what exactly is html4 and css2 in your understanding :-D ?

Answer (score 0):

First read how to use the slider plugin.

For any plugin you need to download plugin package with supported JS, CSS, images files then

```
1. Include required site CSS file and plugin CSS file

2. Include jQuery file

3. Include dependency files for the plugin if needed 
   (some plugin require jqueryui, mousewheel,etc)

4. Write the HTML content code as instructed in plugin document for your requirement. 
   (something like <div class='my-slider'><ul><li>item1 </li></div> etc)

5. Configure the HTML content with jQuery plugin. This happens usually at document.ready event.Like

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.my-slider').pluginfunction(); // .slider();
});
```